# How do I set a default parameter value in powershell?

Tags: powershell, function, default-parameters

I have the following function that converts a file to Base64.
How do I make it so this function accepts a default value for the file path if one is not entered?

B64 -f $filePath

```
function B64{
    
    param (
    
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
    [Alias("file")]
    $f

    )

    
    $File = "\converted.txt"
    $FilePath = ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")+$File)

    $Content = Get-Content -Path $f 
    $converted = [convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Content))
    $numChar = $converted.length
    $incriment = 275

    $pre = "STRING powershell -enc "
    $string = "STRING "

    function splitLines{
        While ($converted)
        { 
        $x,$converted = ([char[]]$converted).where({$_},'Split',$incriment)
        $x -join ''
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
[Parameter (Mandatory = $False, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)]
[Alias("Path", "FullName")]
[string]$File = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath 'converted.txt'
```

When setting a default value on a parameter, you do not set it mandatory so the caller can call the function without adding that parameter.

By adding alias `Path` and/or `FullName` PLUS allowing the parameter to be set using `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`, you also allow the caller piping **objects** that have a `Path` of `FullName` property.

I also strongly advise you to use a better parameter name. As it is now (just the `f`), it confuses with the `-f` [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f)

Finally, if your function always expects a **string**, it wouldn't harm to define it as such using `[string]$File = ...`

<sup>As [mklement0 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71725210/how-do-i-set-a-default-parameter-value-in-powershell/71725540#comment126757834_71725540) if you want to use `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`, you *must* define the parameter variable $File as `[string]`</sup>